# NHibernate Queryover select distinct record

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

i am new to NHibernate and queryover. I would like to write nhibernate query to the following sql.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM V_FDS_BANK_MASTR_ADTWORKFL A,
     (SELECT DISTINCT BANK_CD
        FROM V_FDS_BANK_MASTR_ADTWORKFL
        WHERE TRUNC (APPROVEDBY_DATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE ('18/03/2013',
                                                          'DD/MM/YYYY')
                                             AND TO_DATE ('19/03/2013',
                                                          'DD/MM/YYYY')) B
   WHERE A.BANK_CD = B.BANK_CD
ORDER BY A.BANK_CD, APPROVEDBY_DATE
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = Session.QueryOver<A>()
    .WhereRestrictionOn(a => a.ApprovedDate).Between(date1, date2)
    .OrderBy(a => a.BankCD)
        .ThenBy(a => a.ApprovedDate)
    .List()
```